# How to create anchor link to another page

Tags: navigation

I want to set an anchor link on a page to an anchor on a *different* page. I have been able to do this using CKEditor, specifying the target anchor and then specifying an href for the link in CKEditor to, for example, `/training/classes/#puppy-training`.

This works, but the resulting URL obviously includes the `#`,  instead of `/training/classes/puppy-training`. Is there any way to remove the # mark from the URL?

This is using nodes built with custom content types in Drupal 7. I've also noticed the *Links module*, and wonder if it might be of any any help setting up anchors?

I'm also wondering how to approach this if I was using Views.

Answer (score 2):

If 'puppy-training' is a section on the '/training/classes' page then there is not a way to remove the '#' symbol. The '#' symbol is a fragment identifier. It is supposed to refer to a [location within a resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html#fragment-uri) (i.e., the '/training/classes').

If you would like to have a URL without the '#' symbol, I would recommend creating a separate node for that piece of content.

Comment: Very good to know. Thank you for the detailed explanation.